# Why does focus- assist light on speedlite fire when main flash fires?

Tags: hotshoe-flash, focus-assist

Using a new Gloxy 990 on a Canon 80D hot shoe, the bright red light of the Gloxy Focus Assist is appearing on the image at a wide range of setting. The light works at half press - but must be firing again with the flash?[image: Birthday Cake]

Comment: I'd say it's either broken or there is some setting that enables it as a feature. If the flash talks to the camera, the setting could be either place. Since it does not occur in manual mode, the camera might be the place to start. Adding the camera model to the question might help explore that path.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you think that?  I'm not sure what you are seeing, but I think the assumptions are all wrong.

Focus (and also focus assist) work during focus, before the exposure (at half press, not at full press).

The "red" focus assist is surely infrared (and much brighter than we can see),  to which the exposure is not even sensitive to, if it were to occur at exposure, which it doesn't.

If the hot shoe flash is on the hot shoe, and turned on and ready, then it MUST flash with the shutter exposure.  That's what flashes do.  They flash when you work the shutter.  Anything else would be very disappointing.

Comment: I think @tonyr is seeing the red colored artifacts around the eye on the right side of the cake face. The eye itself shows a red reflection in the approximate location of the flash.

Comment: Yes Ben, the red lights around the right hand eye on the cake are the same location and distribution as the bright, visible, lights emitted at half press. Moving to Manual avoids this but I cannot understand why it is present in the flash shot, unless the Gloxy is faulty?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm surprised that I failed to even notice that before, but it's clearly obvious after you point it out.  I've never seen AF Assist blink, but it does have a duration to assist focusing.  Maybe the shutter button was just jabbed quickly, not providing much time between half press and full press?   I cannot duplicate it with my flashes.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. I assume unless you had used a flash with that disposition of red lights you may have thought the red was simply an adornment of the cake illumination - quite pretty really. It is not due to 'jabbing' the shutter release - that had occurred to me. Thus I did a half press focus - and then paused longer than one would normally - and still got the effect. As an aside to this I have am playing with a Kenro speedflash this evening(bought in error at the same time), and at some setting found the pre focus red visible light firing continually.

Comment: Hi Ben. Missed your post - newbie to this layout.I thought Canon 80D covered it. I agree it may be camera setting dependent. As I said to Wayne, I am playing with a Kenro - very similar in many ways. As someone whose only flash experience was the Jessops kit one with my Canon 400D years ago, and flash bulbs before that, I find the 'Instruction manuals' a bit thin. Two 'intelligent' bits of gear and getting them to talk is a problem.

Comment: @TonyR   If it continues to repeatedly fire assist, you should be able to see it while you hold half press.  My Nikon, Yongnuo and Neewer flashes just fire once (a slightly longer duration), but do not continue when held.  But Assist probably is a camera function.   And they do not fire even once in the continuous focus mode (Nikon AF-C).